# WSO2 ESB 4.7 SVN-Based Deployment Synchronizer - Error

Tags: svn, wso2, wso2-esb

I have ESB cluster with one manager node and 4 worker nodes using svn based deployment synchronizer. It was working without any issue for a few years. 10 days back deployment synchronizer removed few proxy services and APIs. Most of these proxy services and APIs are heavily used. I created a new repository from backup and configured all the nodes with new repository. Today morning again deployment synchronizer deleted few proxy services and APIs. I added back those proxy services and APIs from my backup but after sometime deployment synchronizer deleting proxy services randomly. I think this issue could be due to corrupted servicemeta files or other resources in the repository. Please suggest me steps to resolve this issue. This becomes big pain point as it is deleting resources randomly.

```
TID: [0] [ESB]   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'adminUsercarbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-11-10 08:35:04,078-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB]   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'adminUsercarbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-11-10 08:35:05,285-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB]   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Removing Axis2 Service: ServiceXYZ_1.0.100.5000 {super-tenant} {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor}
TID: [0] [ESB]   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'adminUsercarbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-11-10 08:35:05,599-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB]   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'adminUsercarbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-11-10 08:35:05,804-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB]   INFO {org.apache.synapse.rest.API} -  Destroying API: ServiceXYZ_API/1.0.100.5000 {org.apache.synapse.rest.API}
TID: [0] [ESB]   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask} -  Sent [SynchronizeRepositoryRequest{tenantId=-1234, tenantDomain='carbon.super', messageId=86de8bcf-7b86-450d-b97e-61d47e5112c9}] {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask}
TID: [0] [ESB]   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'adminUsercarbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-11-10 08:38:03,369-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB]   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'adminUsercarbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-11-10 08:38:03,650-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB]   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Removing Axis2 Service: ServiceTest_1.0.101.6000 {super-tenant} {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor}
TID: [0] [ESB]   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'adminUsercarbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-11-10 08:38:03,792-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB]   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'adminUsercarbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-11-10 08:38:03,893-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB]   INFO {org.apache.synapse.rest.API} -  Destroying API: ServiceTest_API/1.0.101.6000 {org.apache.synapse.rest.API}
TID: [0] [ESB]   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask} -  Sent [SynchronizeRepositoryRequest{tenantId=-1234, tenantDomain='carbon.super', messageId=c2b3bf43-a39a-46d2-93b1-bd43e55b5d31}] {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask}
TID: [0] [ESB]   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'adminUsercarbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-11-10 08:41:02,449-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB]  ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyServiceAdmin} -  A proxy service named : ServiceTest_1.0.101.6000 does not exist {org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyServiceAdmin}
org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.ProxyAdminException: A proxy service named : ServiceTest_1.0.101.6000 does not exist
                at org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyServiceAdmin.handleException(ProxyServiceAdmin.java:978)
                at org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyServiceAdmin.proxyForName(ProxyServiceAdmin.java:714)
                at org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyServiceAdmin.getProxy(ProxyServiceAdmin.java:668)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
                at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
                at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
                at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
                at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
                at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
                at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
                at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
                at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:177)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:161)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [0] [ESB]  ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyServiceAdmin} -  Unable to get the proxy service definition for : ServiceTest_1.0.101.6000 :: A proxy service named : ServiceTest_1.0.101.6000 does not exist {org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyServiceAdmin}
org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.ProxyAdminException: A proxy service named : ServiceTest_1.0.101.6000 does not exist
                at org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyServiceAdmin.handleException(ProxyServiceAdmin.java:978)
                at org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyServiceAdmin.proxyForName(ProxyServiceAdmin.java:714)
                at org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyServiceAdmin.getProxy(ProxyServiceAdmin.java:668)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
                at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
                at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
                at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
                at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
                at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
                at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
                at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
                at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:177)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:161)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
                at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [0] [ESB]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'adminUsercarbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-11-10 08:41:02,580-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'adminUsercarbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-11-10 08:44:02,165-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'adminUsercarbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-11-10 08:44:02,371-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Removing Axis2 Service: ServiceABC_1.0.200.7000 {super-tenant} {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor}
TID: [0] [ESB] [  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'adminUsercarbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-11-10 08:44:03,570-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
```

Comment: What were the recent changes done to cause this issue? Did you delete/add/modify any existing artifacts? Any change on the cluster environment?

Comment: No changes to the cluster environment. some time back I backup proxy service by renaming the .xml file and forgot to change proxy service name. Later I deleted the backup file. Other than that there are no changes. The metafile size of removed proxy service is 1 KB. This issue happening very frequently last few days. I disabled deployment synchronizer in the cluster environment.  I also did svnadmin verify on the repository but no errors.